# How to store docusign form information into saleforce case object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, docusign

I have one requirement regarding Docusign. Docusign form will be generated from salesforce link,user will fill the form and on click of save, case record should be created. In what way I can achieve this functionality? Can anyone help me in finding the way?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The signed form gets placed into the case object in the related list named case comments. If this is what you had meant, then you need to make a connection in docusign first as explained here on page 89 http://e4354b6ce7c46ea73946-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.r36.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-for-salesforce-administrator-guide.pdf

I hope that this answered your question.